# I can't find the relevant part of the loop in my theme file. How do I find the full content with "More..."

Tags: posts, theme-development, loop

Brunelleschi is based on the Twenty-Ten theme, but has really grown since then. I like my theme, but I'm trying to modify the way a posts in page plugin works and I need to copy the relevant part of the loop to do it.

1. I want to display full posts, but have them cut off at the "more..." spot.
2. In this theme, it says "Continue Reading."
3. The original code for the plugin below:

   ```
           <div class="entry-summary">
           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
       </div>
   ```

The big issue with this is that excerpts are formatted differently and use a specific truncation and no pictures, whereas cutting off at the "more" is a manual thing, which I want.

So I modified the code to:

```
            <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
```

This displays full content, but it does not cut off at the "more." So I go hunting in the loop and try replacing the code with just about every potentially relevant snippet I can find in the loop.php theme file and nothing works. They do post formats, wonky image galleries (sort of), or the full content. I've pastebinned the loop.php. I just need help finding which snippet to copy over 'cause it's not working even though it does work in the regular templated pages, just not on the embedded posts in pages.

[The brunelleschi loop code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Kd8eJryw)

EDITED TO ADD:

I keep thinking it should be this particular snippet:

```
                                <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'brunelleschi' ) ); ?>
```

But when I use that instead of the version without args, it still shows the full post despite having manual more tags in those posts.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but: have you added the `<!--more-->` quicktag to your posts, to define the cutoff point?

Comment: I think that [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Read_More_Techniques) article in WordPress codex should help you understand the matter better. :)

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes, I have.

Comment: @pogoking Looking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to override the `$more` default. Do this:

```
        <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php 
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        the_content(); ?>
    </div>
```

It is a solution pretty much [straight from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Overriding_Archive.2FSingle_Page_Behavior).

Comment: Well, it does create a more, but it doesn't do it the way the theme does, so I'll see if I can find something that looks like this in the theme file. That's my only problem. Not theming, finding what the theme already did. I'm straight copy/pasting here.

Comment: That is how WordPress deals with `<--more-->` content. If the theme is doing something else you are going to have to find the relevant code and paste it into your question. I was going to say to look for `add_filter( 'the_content'` or `add_filter( 'the_excerpt'` with or without the space, but those should work with the code above. The theme must be doing something of its own devising.

Comment: Yes, and I've been trying and not finding, which is WHY I pastebinned the file and asked for help looking from more knowledgeable eyes than my own. It didn't seem that much to ask for.

Comment: It is a fair question-- I don't think I suggested otherwise-- but the problem is not in the file you posted on the pastebin, at least not that I can see. I also don't see anything that would make me think the typical `the_content` and `the_excerpt` functions and filters won't work, but you are (in effect) telling me they don't. If I'd seen anything odd in that file, I would have suggested a different solution (if I had one).

Comment: Brunelleschi appears to use three different versions: the_content which shows the full post, the_excerpt which shows a severely truncated version and the I-don't-know-what which shows the teaser/full content version. Do you think the issue is in the div class?

Comment: "Do you think the issue is in the div class? " No, it won't be an HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: Okay figured out how to combine that snippet with the override and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: @LianaMir "Okay figured out how to combine that snippet with the override and it worked! Thank you."* - Would you mind **editing this answer** to include your final code examples?

Comment: @ChipBennett I did edit the answer to include my final code, and the edit apparently got booted.